# I have some troubles with authentication in istio

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, istio, kubeflow

I do all this on my server.

I followed this guide https://www.deploykf.org/guides/local-quickstart/.

I reached the end of the guide and now I can’t reach my kubeflow.

I added what I thought were valid JWT users.

[image]
[image]

But for the most common request I get an error I get a 401 status code and an error "Jwt issuer is not configured"
[image]

If I send empty headers I get 'Jwt is missing'

Please help me.

Requests handling
[image]

I didn't find how to disable the check JWT

I tried adding JWT, but it didn't help with authentication

Comment: I am a little confused, have you made any manual changes to the manifests?

Comment: Also, why are you using `https://127.0.0.1:8443` you should be using an actual domain name (possibly by modifying your `/etc/hosts`), as described by the last step in the guide: https://www.deploykf.org/guides/local-quickstart/#access-the-gateway

Comment: @MathewWicks  Thank you, but I gave up on it because it was for uni